# Error on returning Generic Type (No implicit Conversion)

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Getting an implicit conversion exception when calling a generic method. What is the right way of doing this?

Here are my interface and class definitions:

```
public interface TestData
{
    string field { get; set; }
    string fieldName { get; set; }
    string type { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static T Call<T>(string Project, string type) where T : TestData
    {
        var returning = GETCG<T>(test, type);

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(returning, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private static T GETCG<T>(string test, string type) where T : TestData
    {
        var fields = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => new
        {
            // some data
        }).ToList();

        if (fields != null)
        {
            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(templateFields, typeof(T), 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType("SomeString", typeof(T), 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TestClass.Call(string, string)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Test.TestData'

On the line of code below:

```
var test = TestClass.Call<List<TestData>>("ProjName", "Audio");
```

If you see in the `GETCG` method I'm returning different types `List` and `string`. Methods `Call` and `GETCG` implement the interface `TestData`. Can I have an explanation why I'm getting this error and how can I improve this code keeping in mind I need to return both `strings` and `List` from the `TestClass`

Comment: `List<TestData>` does not implement the `where T : TestData` constraint

Comment: What about abandoning the idea of returning completely different types from method? And you have defined this constraint `where T: TestData` and you say you want to return a string. Does string even implements/inherits `TestData`?

Comment: @Alexander string doesnt implemeny testdata, but i need to know how to do this as this is a requirement.

Comment: Well, `string` doesn't implement this type and it's not possible to make `string` to do this and your requirement is to do it, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you've defined a constraint on `T` that it must implement the `TestData` interface, however you're declaring `T` as a `List<TestData>`.

The compiler is telling you that `List<T>` does not implement the `TestData` interface and there is no implicit conversion it can use to make that happen.

The solution would be to either remove the constraint or pass in a class instance that implements the `TestData` interface.

Comment: `var test = TestClass.Call<TestData>("ProjName", "Audio");`

Comment: But there are too many unknown objects in the code you posted to give a proper solution. For example, we don't see the definition of `test` used inside the `Call` method, and we don't see the definition of `nodees` or `templateFields` in the `GETCG` method, and how would `return (T)Convert.ChangeType("SomeString", typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` work if there is no conversion defined for `string -> TestType`?

Comment: I guess this should work, im not at desk now, will test and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Will definitely provide more information or update my question once im back at desk. Thanks

Comment: That seems fine after I made the change to `var test = TestClass.Call<TestData>("ProjName", "Audio");`, but now I'm getting error at `return (T) Convert.ChangeType(templateFields, typeof(T), 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. The error says: `Object must implement ICONVERTIBLE`